# Is there a way to associate a work item to a Pull Request after its been merged

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, pull-request

Our group's standard is to related work items to pull requests.  Is there a way to do that after a PR has already been merged?  One of our developers forgot.

Thanks.

Comment: A pull request contains a branch. The branch's tip is a unique commit. Associate the work item to the commit.

Comment: Thank you, but how do I do that after it has been merged?

Comment: How do you do it before the merge?

Comment: In the Pull Request there is a box for "Related Work Items".

Comment: Was it a normal merge or a squash merge?